# ISO transclusion in emacs org-mode

Tags: emacs, include, org-mode, transclusion

Q: is there any way to do transclusion in emacs org-mode?

By "transclusion", I mean stuff like, at some point in fileA.org and fileB.org, "including" fileInc.org - and having the tree from fileInc.org appear in both places.  Actually appear, not just be linked to.
(Possibly with conditional inclusion, transformation, e.g. nesting depth (number of ***s)).

I know about #setupfile, but that seems only to work for modes, not real text.

I know about http://orgmode.org/manual/Include-files.html,
but AFAIK they only work at export time.

I am looking for something that works in a normal emacs org-mode buffer.
(Actually, something that worked in non-org-mode buffers might be nice.)

I have boiler plate that I want to include in multiple files.

Does something like this exist?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Hmm... I don't think anything like this exists, but it was easy enough to write a dynamic block to do this.  The following elisp works for me:

```
(defun org-dblock-write:transclusion (params)
  (progn
    (with-temp-buffer
      (insert-file-contents (plist-get params :filename))
      (let ((range-start (or (plist-get params :min) (line-number-at-pos (point-min))))
            (range-end (or (plist-get params :max) (line-number-at-pos (point-max)))))
        (copy-region-as-kill (line-beginning-position range-start)
                             (line-end-position range-end))))
    (yank)))
```

Then to include a line range from a given file, you can create a dynamic block like so:

```
 #+BEGIN: transclusion :filename "~/testfile.org" :min 2 :max 4
 #+END:
```

And auto-populate with `C-c C-x C-u`.  Skip the min and max args to include the entire file.  Note that you can bind `org-update-all-dblocks` to a hook, so that this range is updated whenever you visit the file or save.

More info on dynamic blocks at http://orgmode.org/org.html#Dynamic-blocks.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Has anyone adapted this to take particular headlines? I haven't found anything public yet (I posted a related question here if anyone does find or make something like this http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12562/org-mode-headings-in-multiple-places-at-once-transclusion

Comment: It would be nice to make it work with tags the way `#+INCLUDE` does.

Comment: Could you please explain, what is the meaning of the column in the name of the function?

Comment: In 2021, as per u/rdgrg109's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68767694/172406), [org-transclusion on github](https://github.com/nobiot/org-transclusion) is the way to go

Answer (score 3):

You might be interested in the package `org-transclusion` [(Github repository)](https://github.com/nobiot/org-transclusion).